# SharePoint calculated column based on value of another field

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to do some automated scoring based on the values of various Choice fields:

Column name is **Project**

Choice values are **Widgets1**, **Widgets2** and **Widgets3**

The scoring is based on the choice of widgets:

- Widgets1 is 10 points
- Widgets2 is 25
- Widgets3 is 50

In the same record is a field titled **Score**. I want this dynamically populated based on the above choice. For example if widgets3 is selected, then our score is 50.

ALSO: I have some fields that are Y/N, and am hoping the syntax is similar.

Can someone point me in the right direction with the right syntax to make this happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The Score column would be a Calculated Column with this formula:

```
=IF( Project = "Widgets1", 10, 
 IF( Project = "Widgets2", 25, 
 IF( Project = "Widgets3", 50,
 0 )
```

The formula for a Yes/No might look like this:

```
=IF( YesNo, 100, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mike,

I had to make a few minor changes, but got it to work:

=IF( [Project] = "Widgets1", 10,

IF( [Project] = "Widgets2", 25,

IF( [Project] = "Widgets3", 50,

0 )))

Thanks again - all good!